# In jQuery how can I get the next selector in a nested loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="foo">
     <div class="moo">
            <div class="too"> <input type="hidden" val="56"/></div>
     </div>       
</div>
<div class="foo">
     <div class="moo">
            <div class="too">  <input type="hidden" val="58"/></div>
     </div>       
</div>
```

Continued...

```
//jQuery Code
$('.too').live('click',function(){
  var next_value = $(this).next('.too').find('input').val();
  console.log(next_value);
});
```

Now I want the value of the next "too" input. How can I get this? It's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `.next()` traverses sibling elements. One approach would be to climb up the DOM tree, then back down. For example:

```
$('.foo').on('click', '.too', function () {
  var next_value = $(this).closest('.foo').next().find('input').val();
});
```

Also, you should try to avoid `.live()`. If you are using jQuery 1.7+, you'll want to use `.on()` (as shown in my example). If you are using anything before 1.7, try `.delegate()` or `.bind()`.

Comment: .on() is pretty much a drop in replacement for .live()

Comment: Not necessarily, @BrianDilley. `.live()` traverses all the way from the top of the DOM tree, which is just about the least efficient way to go about it. Using `.on()` as I have in my example will only listen for events within the specified container.

Comment: `.parent` will not work because of `.moo`.  You should use `.closest`.  As for "specific reason" to not use `.live`, the best reason is because it's deprecated and will be removed from future jQuery versions.

Comment: Good call, @ExplosionPills. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First off, do not use `.live`.  Use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Second, `.next` only works with siblings.  You can get the next sibling in a variety of ways -- assuming that the the `.foo` / `.too` structure is unique to the document, you can use the following:

```
var next_value = $(".too").eq($('.too').index(this) + 1);
```

Comment: That's not a bad way to go about it!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.too').live('click',function(){
  var next_value = $(this).parent('.foo').next().find('input').val();
  console.log(next_value);
});
```

by the way,i think you should give up `.live()`.